# Boeing 787. Creating the windshield. How would you approach it? Help

Tags: modeling

So I'm modeling a Boeing 787-8 commercial jet and I've gotten to the very sleek and flush windshield section. I've cut a *beautiful* set of window frames but now Im stuck with this situation of creating the windows into the frame, while maintaining the natural curve of the nose. I know it's a bit of a complex curve especially

Joining the vertices closes the gap, but it looks absolutely terrible and neglects that curvature that needs to be there. How would you go about creating this or approaching this? Thanks in advance. I've included pictures of the situation, a reference and what the rest of the model looks like so far.

[image: window frames][image: my bullshit windows][image: the actual 787][image: what the rest of my model looks like so far]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your window cannot be a single face otherwise it will not follow the contour of the plain. I'm assuming you have a number of edge loops that were originally passing through that area from the plane body. You'll need to recreate and connect all those edge loops so that you end up with a window area that looks like a grid. Then if you need to you can gently pull out the middle of the window with proportional editing to precisely match the contour of the body.